# How to concatenate img src in html

Tags: html, arrays, string, image

My goal here is to create a table with many images. By doing that, I'm going trough an array that has the location of that image. My issue is, how do I turn this string into a dynamic one:

```
 <td><img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/ + local.weather[0].icon +.png"></td>
```

The "local.weather[0].icon" is the dynamic part. I can't seem to figure out a way for this to work.

Comment: try `src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + local.weather[0].icon + ".png"`

Comment: @AneesIjaz I tried that before, but for some reason, the ".png" part doesn't turn into a string

Comment: I guess you will have to do it using js.

Comment: @AneesIjaz I got the same error. the ".png" section turns white and doesn't turn into a string. Where should I put the " " ? or should I use ' ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to do it manually in js. (you cannot add the src attribute dynamically on page load. for that you will have to do it either server or change it via js on window load)
try the code below.

```
<td><img id="weatherImg"></td>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById("weatherImg").src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${local.weather[0].icon}.png`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Template Strings.

```
here is the example,
var val = 'fortnite'
var x = 'I play ${val}';
console.log(x);     // I play fortnite
val = 'pubg'
console.log(x);     // I play pubg
//so I have made that dynamic using template strings. Use ` key instead for quotes.
[![This is the key][1]][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand that. I was trying to find a way to do that inside the html element, instead of doing it on js and then loading it on the table.